# Why adding class path caused main class not found?

Tags: java

I get a NoClassDefFoundError when trying to run a Java class without providing the proper class path. However when added the needed class path, java complaints it cannot find the main method. If you have any idea of what's happening here, please point me in the right direction. Thank you

```
$ java MyClass
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cern/colt/matrix/DoubleMatrix1D
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    ... 6 more

$ java -cp resources/colt.jar MyClass
Error: Could not find or load main class MyClass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `MyClass` isn't in a package, you need something like (on Windows)

```
java -cp resources/colt.jar;. MyClass
```

or (otherwise)

```
java -cp resources/colt.jar:. MyClass
```

To also include the current directory. Alternatively, you can set the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

On Windows,

```
set "CLASSPATH=resources/colt.jar;."
```

otherwise something like (depending on your shell)

```
export CLASSPATH="resources/colt.jar:."
```

then

```
java MyClass
```

Answer (score 1):

try to include the current directory in the classpath as well. usually we add new jars to classpath liek this:

```
java -cp %CLASSPATH%;resource/colt.jar MyClass
```

or on Linux as:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH:resource/colt.jar MyClass
```

Additionally u can also add .

i.e the currrent directory to the classpath.